# How to make a fully configurable piano for iPad

Tags: xcode, touch-event, piano

I will program a fully configurable piano. On some piano examples I have noticed, that keys are "hanging", when sliding with the fingers over them. Has somebody an example how to handle "touch began", "touch ended" and "touch moved" correctly?
Thanks and best Regards

Comment: In the docs for `UIResponder` look at the sample code list under "More related items...".  One of the entries is a project called "Handling Touches Using Responder Methods and Gesture Recognizers".

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for me. The problem was, that after treating all "touches ended" events, there were sometimes remaining touches events of type "touches moved" in the iOS touch queue that weren't fired to the "touches moved" method until an other touch was done (e.g. outside of the object or a new touch in the object). So I call the "touches moved" method in the "touches ended" method. May be this is not a good way to do it and somebody has a better propose.

I have implemented the piano in the App's "AAccompanist", "AccordionPlus", MIDItoolsPlus". I could provide some sample code.